# replace regular expression with its input mask ( 200 kind )

Tags: java, regex

For records:

**X** means anything

**Y** means year

**M** means month

**N** means numeric

**A** means alphabet

For example:

my input mask from database is like this:

```
XXXYMXXXXXA
```

and my input is:

```
39JY412345O
```

i want check this input is valid or invalid but i can't check it with mask, I want replace mask with regular expression like this for its input mask:

```
 /^.{3}Y[0-9]{1}.{5}[a-zA-Z]{1}$/
```

I don't have regular expression, I have input mask only.I have input validation and it use regular expression for checking valid or invalid inputs. I should replace regular expression with my input mask ( 200 kind of input mask ) and I use its regular expression for validation

I need to write a method that translates from an input mask (such as "XXXYMXXXXXA") to a regex in the java.lang.regex.Pattern format (such as ".{3}Y[0-9]{1}.{5}[a-zA-Z]{1}")

This is my method code: ( **but I want best practice for this solution** )

```
private String replaceAll(String pattern, String value, String replaceValue) {
    String str = value;
    str = str.replaceAll(pattern, replaceValue.concat("{").concat("1").concat("}"));
    return str;
}
```

and method calls:

```
String anything = "[Xx]";
String alphabet = "[Aa]";
String number = "[Nn]";
String word = getName();

word = replaceAll(anything, word, ".");
word = replaceAll(alphabet, word, "[A-Za-z]");
word = replaceAll(number, word, "[0-9]");
```

Comment: so you want to use `regex` instead of `mask`..right! also in java,you don't have to put `/` around regex

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you need to write a method that translates from an input mask (such as `"XXXYMXXXXXA"`) to a regex in the `java.lang.regex.Pattern` format (such as `".{3}Y[0-9]{1}.{5}[a-zA-Z]{1}"`). Is that correct?

Comment: i don't have any regular expression
my question is how to replace regex with its input mask?

Comment: yes yes, finally someone got it :D thanks god :)

Comment: @ruakh yes, is it possible?and how?

Comment: @Navid_gh: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: @ruakh he has mentioned the `regex` in his question

Comment: @ruakh at first i want use regular expression replacement but it seems it not possible, now i wrote this method:

`private String replaceAll(String pattern, String value, String replaceValue) {
String str = value;
while (true) {
Pattern compile = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(str);
            matcher.find();
            if (matcher.hitEnd()) {
                break;
            }
            str = str.replaceFirst(pattern, replaceValue.concat("{").concat(String.valueOf(matcher.group(1).length())).concat("}"));
        }
        return str;
    }`

Comment: @ruakh I added my method to my question content
Please tell me best practice for this solution, I prefer use regular expression replacement replace java method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a general approach, there is a mapping between one char in the mask (e.g. `'X'`) to one part of a regular expression (e.g. `'.'`), and recurrent mask chars result in a numeric quantifier (like `{3}`).

So I've put together a helper class, and a simple test method, so maybe this is a point to start from.

Helper class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class PatternBuilder {

    protected Map<Character, String> mappings = new HashMap<Character, String>();
    protected boolean caseSensitive = false;

    public PatternBuilder() {
    }

    public PatternBuilder(boolean caseSensitive) {
        this.caseSensitive = caseSensitive;
    }

    public PatternBuilder addDefinition(char input, String mapping) {
        if (this.caseSensitive) {
            this.mappings.put(input, mapping);
        } else {
            this.mappings.put(Character.toLowerCase(input), mapping);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public String buildRegexPattern(String mask) {
        if ((mask == null) || (mask.length() == 0))  {
            return "";
        }
        StringBuilder patternBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        char lastChar = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mask.length(); i++) {
            char c = mask.charAt(i);
            if (this.caseSensitive == false) {
                c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
            }
            if (c != lastChar) {
                if (count > 0) {
                    String mapped = mappings.get(lastChar);
                    if (mapped == null) {
                        // mapping for char not defined
                        return "";
                    }
                    patternBuffer.append(mapped);
                    patternBuffer.append("{").append(count).append("}");
                }
                lastChar = c;
                count = 1;
            } else {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count > 0) {
            String mapped = mappings.get(lastChar);
            if (mapped == null) {
                mapped = ".";
            }
            patternBuffer.append(mapped);
            patternBuffer.append("{").append(count).append("}");
        }
        return patternBuffer.toString();
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
PatternBuilder patternBuilder = new PatternBuilder()
        .addDefinition('X', ".")
        .addDefinition('Y', "Y")
        .addDefinition('M', "[0-9]")
        .addDefinition('N', "\\d")
        .addDefinition('A', "[a-zA-Z]");
String rePattern = patternBuilder.buildRegexPattern("XxxYMXXXXXA"); // case insensitive, x == X
System.out.println("Pattern: '" + rePattern + "'");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(rePattern);

String[] tests = new String[]{
    "39JY412345O", // Original, match
    "39JY41234FO", // replaced 5 with F, still matching
    "39JY4123457", // replaced O with 7, no match
    "A9JY4123457"  // replaced 3 with A, no match
};        
for (String s : tests) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    System.out.println("Test '" + s + "': " + m.matches());
}
```

My output:

```
Pattern: '.{3}Y{1}[0-9]{1}.{5}[a-zA-Z]{1}'
Test '39JY412345O': true
Test '39JY41234FO': true
Test '39JY4123457': false
Test 'A9JY4123457': false
```